# Changing domain password from TS box inside VPC VM

Tags: windows, passwords, virtual-pc

I'm running a VirtualPC 2007 VM with Windows2003 as the OS.  Inside of this I am using a web based VPN to connect to my client's network.  I cannot use this VPN from my host machine because it does not work with Vista (still!).  Inside the VM I'm connecting to a Terminal Server at the client site which I'm logging into using their domain.

I need to change my password.  Obviously what you would normally do is hit ctrl-alt-del and click change password.  However since I'm inside of a TS inside of a VM this is not an option.  When logging in to the VM I have to press alt-(left arrow)-del and then type in my password.  I also know that usually when using remote desktop, in order to simulate a ctrl-alt-del inside there you would press ctrl-alt-end.  With this knowledge, I've tried every possible combination of these keys that I can think of, but none of them bring up the Windows Security Dialog Box.

What I'm looking for is either

1. A way to open the Windows Security Dialog Box (or simply the change password form from there) without pressing ctrl-alt-del (is there a command line I can use?)
2. A different way to change my domain password without using the aforementioned box